# What's the meaning of the keyword 'statics' in ES5

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm encapsulating a Menu called JellMenu, and I want to expose CustomMenuItem like `JellMenu.Item` instead of `import CustomMenuItem`. I have no idea how to do.

I took look at `react-native-viewpager` source code, and I think this maybe helpful:

```
var ViewPager = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    DataSource: ViewPagerDataSource,
  },
```

It will expose `ViewPagerDataSource` as `ViewPager.DataSource`, right? I don't know exactly. what's the meaning of the keyword `statics` in Es5, and what's the alternative in Es6? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `statics` isn't a keyword.

Comment: @nnnnnn: No, it's a react thing (and ES5 didn't have `static`, it just reserved it as a "future reserved word" in strict mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a keyword, it's just a property name in an object initializer being passed to `React.createClass`. From [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#statics), it's used to specify static (non instance-specific) parts of a React class:

> The `statics` object allows you to define static methods that can be called on the component class.

Comment: I want to use it in `class xx extends Component` instead of 'React.createClass`, what's the alternative?

Comment: @CoderGLM: I don't know much about React (it's on my list to investigate!), but in ES2015 ("ES6") and above, you'd specify each static method individually: `class xx extends Component { static foo() { } }`. ES2015 doesn't have static fields yet (there's [a proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) though).

Answer (score 0):

Although `statics` only works for `React.createClass`, you can still write static methods in ES6 notation. If you are using ES7, then you can also write static properties.The `statics` object allows you to define static methods that can be called on the component class. For example:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    customMethod: function(foo) {
    return foo === 'bar';
  }
},
render: function() {

   }
});
MyComponent.customMethod('bar');  // true
```

Methods defined within this block are `static`, meaning that you can run them before any component instances are created, and the methods do not have access to the `props` or `state` of your components. If you want to check the value of props in a `static method`, have the `caller` pass in the `props as an argument` to the static method.

Also, You can write statics inside ES6+ classes this way:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
 static propTypes = {
  ...
 }

 static someMethod(){
 }
}
```

Or outside the class like this:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
 ....
}

Component.propTypes = {...}
Component.someMethod = function(){....}
```